# Passing Intel-PT to guest using QEMU/KVM doesn't work

Tags: linux, intel, qemu, virtualization, kvm

I am trying to use Intel-PT feature inside a guest ubuntu using QEMU/KVM, but although I have this feature in the host, KVM is not passing this feature to the guest.

Also when I try to load kvm_intel module in host with pt_mode=1 it doesn't work:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r kvm_intel kvm
$ sudo modprobe kvm_intel pt_mode=1
$ sudo modprobe kvm
$ cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/pt_mode
0
```

I've tried lots of different kernel versions but still I have the problem.

Comment: If `modprobe kvm_intel pt_mode=1` is going to do anything, it would have to be in the *host* system.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But did it in the host. @PeterCordes